# Messenger Bot template message giving error for subscription permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I have developed a messenger bot and also got approval for the page_messaging from facebook and it works great. Now as per the Facebook terms and guidelines for subscription messaging mentioned here(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview#subscription_messaging) for Standard Messaging means the page_messaging permission which we have it says:

> "Messages cannot be sent beyond 24 hours from any triggering action, as described above. Exceptions include template messages and one additional bonus message outside of the 24 hours to follow up on the conversation."

Here it's clearly mentioned that template messages are exceptional and can be sent even after 24 hour period but when we are trying to send message after 24 hour it is asking for subscription permission and giving following error:

```
{"error":{"message":"(#230) Requires pages_messaging_subscriptions permission to manage the object","type":"OAuthException","code":230,"fbtrace_id":"FAfXwRoT\/ta"}}
```

So, when facebook says that the template messages are exceptional and can be sent after 24 hour period then why it is giving subscription permission error for template message?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: “Additional bonus message” could mean that you need to have replied to the user in the 24 hour window beforehand. Is that the case, resp. did you try if that changes anything?

Comment: One additional bonus message is for text message as of what i understood but for template message it says that's exception so that means we can send template messages after 24 hours window as well even if there is no response.. If in case user responds to message then error goes away and reply gets delivered for response for next 24 hours window as of my testing..

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the policy [page you mentioned](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/policy-overview#subscription_messaging), it clearly states that

> Exceptions include receipt and airlines templates as well as tagged
>   generic template

If you're sending generic template messages outside the 24+1 window, make sure that they're [tagged](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/tags). If they're not, they'll throw the error above.

Comment: Facebook updated the Exception part as the previous message was what i have  mentioned above in my question. So previously it was not that clear but now Facebook have given the clear clarification about what will be the exception.